# is it possible to use FB.ui to generate share dialogue and use that for FB.api to post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to post on my fb apps users wall a link with FB.api function. but I want to give the user full control over what they post as we have in fb.ui.
for example, I'm using this code to post on wall-

```
function fb_share(){

var currentPageUrlIs =document.location.href;

var params = {};
params['access_token'] = FB.getAuthResponse().accessToken;
params['link'] ='http://rasselmahmud.com/sonardesh';
params['message'] ="hello world";

FB.api(FB.ui("me/feed", "post",params, function (response) {
  if (response && !response.error) {
    /* handle the result */
  }
 }
);

}
```

and it's working fine to post.

and using this code to popup the share dialogue

```
      FB.ui({method: 'share',href: 'http://rasselmahmud.com/sonerdesh'}, 
                  // callback
                  function(response) {
                    if (response && !response.error_code) {
                      alert('Posting completed.');

                    } else {
                      alert('Sorry we could not post on your wall. please     try again..');
                    }
                  }
                ) ;
```

this code is also working fine.

now what I want to do is- using the popup generated by FB.ui() function for the FB.api() function so that user can enjoy all the features they enjoy in that pop up.

please help me anyone with a solution or suggest me what else way it can be done...

Comment: why not just use FB.ui? you would have to recreate the popup, which is pretty pointless. also, FB.ui does not need user login.

Comment: thank you @luschn . but unfortunately i need it badly. can you tell me how can I tag people or location or emotions(feeling) with post if I want to post with FB.api ?

Comment: `FB.api(FB.ui("me/feed", …` – trying to “nest” those calls into one another this way makes no sense _whatsoever_. // The possibilities to tag users in posts made via API are fairly limited. You are really better off by just using the dialog, and let the user make the post themselves. And since you’re saying that you want users to have full control, I can’t see why you would ”need” any other way in the first place.